# Can I specify the elements of a dynamically allocated array with a macro constant by using new?

Tags: c++, macros, constants, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation

I know it does not make much sense since one of the purposes to choose the allocation on the heap is to provide the number of elements by a variable object but can I specify the number of elements of an dynamically allocated array with a macro constant?

Like, f.e.:

```
int* ptr = new int[SIZE];
```

with the macro constant of `SIZE`:

```
#define SIZE 25
```

---

I´ve already tested it with g++ and the compiler has passed it without an error or a warning. But that does not mean that it caused no issues or maybe is Undefined Behavior.

- Can I specify the elements of a dynamically allocated array with a macro constant in C++?

Comment: `#define SIZE 25` why would you ever use a macro instead of a proper variable, like `constexpr int SIZE = 25;` ?

Comment: `new int [25]` is valid and hence `new int [SIZE]` is too

Comment: @JesperJuhl If the situation fits, Why I shouldn´t? What makes `constexp int SIZE = 25;` better than using a macro?

Comment: @JesperJuhl One usage case would be where the value of `SIZE` varies between builds for different target platforms (placing the `#define SIZE xx` inside conditional pre-processor directives).

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica If someone decides to use the name `SIZE` for anything (e.g. a local variable or for variable/function at namespace scope), you macro will break it. That won't happen with `constexpr int SIZE` (unless the new object is declared at the exact same scope).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I specify the elements of a dynamically allocated array with a
>   macro constant in C++?

Short answer: Yes!

Reason: Macros that are specified with the `#define` directive are evaluated, and *replaced by the evaluated values*, by the **pre-processor** - that is, **before** the actual compiler gets to work on the code. Thus, given your (previous) `#define SIZE 25` line, the code:

```cpp
int* ptr = new int[SIZE];
```

will, to the compiler, be ***exactly equivalent*** to:

```cpp
int* ptr = new int[25];
```

In fact, such usage of macros is quite common - for example, in code that has to be built for different platforms, where the value of `SIZE` would vary between such builds. For example, one could *conditionally* define `SIZE` as follows:

```cpp
#ifdef PLATFORM25
#define SIZE 25
#else
#define SIZE 50
#endif
```

Or, one could even define the `SIZE` macro with a compiler command-line option - a switch something like (depending on the compiler):

```
/DSIZE=25
```

Comment: My thought of it was that it might be not permissible because the dynamically allocation would - in my earlier thoughts - not be intended for doing so. Thank you very much.